# I've done some research and I can't find the reason to why the USB ports stop working when trying to boot ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I've looked around a lot at many people's different questions and can't find one that is the same situation as the problem I'm having. Essentially a friend brought me an old PC of theirs with the request that there are some files they want taken off the hard drive. Unfortunately, their version of Windows had corrupted, so my solution was to boot Ubuntu from a USB drive without affecting the hard drive, to access the files and then the computer is going to scrap anyway. Unfortunately, as soon as the ubuntu software starts to load the lights on the keyboard and mouse turn off and when I eventually get to the option of 'Try Ubuntu', neither are responsive. I've tried restarting, I've tried different ports, I've tried unplugging and plugging back in, I've tried a different keyboard and mouse but I cannot find a solution. I installed the latest version of ubuntu from their website. I can use the keyboard in the BIOS settings etc. Anyone know what is happening? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Old PCs sometimes had USB configuration options within the BIOS.